# Render Panel on ajax start - JSF

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

After processing I can render a panel in JSF like

```
<a4j:commandButton id="myButton" render="panelId" .... ></a4j:commandButton>
```

But what if I want to render a panel before sending the request, something like

```
<a4j:commandButton id="myButton" onbegin="panelId" .... ></a4j:commandButton>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? To render something you need data from the server, which you get in response to the request.

Comment: The server has updated data and I want to show that updated (in server) before the request is completed !!

Comment: Then don't do any work in the initial request, just update the page. And when the initial request finished the updat,do an automatic new request that does the real work. One question: what is the actual usecase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked

```
<a4j:commandButton id="myButton" onclick="updateMyPanel();" .... ></a4j:commandButton>

<a4j:jsFunction name="updateMyPanel" render="myPanel">
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

**NOTE:** I tried `onbegin` and `onbeforedomupdate` but both didn't work !!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of logic wouldnt have my preference. So if you really need this, here is a possible solution:

**XHTML**

```
<a4j:commandButton id="myButton" onbegin="updatePanel()" .... ></a4j:commandButton>

<a4j:jsFunction name="updatePanel"
    render="panelId">
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

*untested though*